# The better technique in this refactoring case?

Tags: vb.net, refactoring, pass-by-value

I need to do some refactoring (actually it's A LOT, but this small step will be very helpful for the whole process). So, let's say I've got this code snippet:

```
If xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/dang") IsNot Nothing Then
    universalNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/dang")
    Type = "dang"
ElseIf xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/nang") IsNot Nothing Then
    universalNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/nang")
    Type = "nang"
ElseIf xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/lang") IsNot Nothing Then
    universalNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/lang")
    Type = "lang"
ElseIf xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/tang") IsNot Nothing Then
    universalNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/tang")
    Type = "tang"
ElseIf xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/xtang") IsNot Nothing Then
    universalNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/xtang")
    Type = "xtang"
End If
```

It's in the body of a big function and I want to take it out to a separate function. So, what I was wondering is whether it will be better to pass both `universalNode` and `Type` by value and just assign to them the values, without the need of returning anything? Is that going to work well or it is risky?

If it was just the `Type` that I'm working on, i.e., then I would just return it, but it's more than 1 variable that is being changed, and both are local variables for the big function, from which I am taking out this code snippet.

Any other suggestions maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the variables by reference (not by value) to the function, it's not a bad practice and should work:

```
Public Sub MyFunc(ByRef node As MyNode, ByRef typ As String) 
    node = ...
    typ = ...
End Sub
```

Or you can return some complex data holder:

```
Public Class MyParams
   Public node As MyNode
   Public typ As String
End Class

Public MyParams MyFunc() 
    Dim result As New MyParams()
    result.node = ...
    result.typ = ...
    Return result
End Sub
```